# Maximum PHP Loops

Tags: php, while-loop

How can I set a maximum of times the loop gives an output (I tried with a while loop, but didn't get it working)?

```
function show_random_thumbs() {

$args = array(
'orderby'        => 'rand',
'post_type'      => 'attachment',
'post_parent'    => null,
'post_mime_type' => 'image',
'post_status'    => 'published',
'numberposts'    => -1,
);
$attachments = get_posts($args);
if ($attachments) {
    foreach ($attachments as $attachment) {
        echo '<a href="';
        echo get_permalink($attachment->post_parent);
        echo '" title="';
        echo get_the_title($attachment->post_parent);
        echo '">';
        $title = get_the_title($attachment->post_parent);
        echo wp_get_attachment_image($attachment->ID, 'thumbnail', false, array('title' => $title) );
        echo '</a>';
    }
}
}
```

Comment: why don't you just use that value for numberposts instead of -1?

Comment: @mishu Post that as an answer! Truly the simplest solution possible here.

Comment: ask your question here -> http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: because i want random images from all posts

Comment: the posts should still be random even if you use a limit.. did you try it?

Comment: @Waarten mishu's solution will work fine for random images from all posts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a counter variable and `break` when it exceeds a certain level.

```
$count = 0;
foreach($array as $element) {
  $count++;

  // do stuff

  if($count == 10) {
    break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use the value you need in your $args array for the key numberposts

Comment: This is by far the best approach for this particular bit of code. It's already designed to limit itself based on a parameter.

Comment: @ceejayoz: thank you for insisting on showing what is preferable, not only what "does the trick" both here and on the comments for the initial question.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you limit the size of the array you're looping through:

```
$attachments = get_posts($args);
if ($attachments) {
     $attachmentsToDisplay = array_slice( $attachments, 0, 50 );
     foreach ($attachmentsToDisplay as $attachment) {
         etc...
     }
}
```

Also not sure what your get_posts() function does but you might want to check $attachments is actually an array before the foreach loop.

Answer (score 0):

You have to introduce a counter variable and break out of the loop if the variable reaches certain value. Or you could just use the [for](http://www.tizag.com/phpT/forloop.php) loop.